# JWPlayer Iframe - stop video using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, jwplayer

I need to be able to stop a JWPlayer Iframe this is the code i am using

html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="popup('video'); stopvideo();" >Click To Close</a>
<iframe src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/scalerokuengine.php" id="rokuvideo" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0" width="960" height="470"> </iframe>
```

javascript:

```
function stopvideo() {
    document.getElementById('rokuvideo').jwplayer().stop();
}
```

This is the code that the iframe is includeing:

```
<div id="se_video" width="100%" height="100%"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://barakyah.embed.scaleengine.net/latest/jwplayer.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer('se_video').setup({
                'flashplayer': 'http://barakyah.embed.scaleengine.net/latest/jwplayer.swf',
                'autostart': 'false',
                'provider': 'rtmp',
                'streamer': 'rtmp://channel.tvstartup.net/barakyah-vod/play/',
                'file': 'sestore1/barakyah/newsystem/tvstartupvideo_Roku-Video_1446408572907.mp4',
                'stretching': 'exactfit',
                'modes': [
                    {
                    'type': 'flash',
                    'src': 'http://barakyah.embed.scaleengine.net/latest/jwplayer.swf'
                    },
                    {
                    'type': 'html5',
                    'config': {
                            'file': 'http://stream.tvstartup.net/barakyah-vod/play/sestore1/barakyah/newsystem/tvstartupvideo_Roku-Video_1446408572907.mp4/playlist.m3u8',
                            'provider': 'video'
                        }
                    }
                    ],
            'bufferlength': '5',
            'width': '940',
            'height': '470'
            });
        </script>
```

Thank You Guys

Comment: You need to access the jwplayer element inside the iframe. Is your iframe in the same domain?

Comment: no but i can change it to the same domain

Comment: Once the iframe is in the same domain try access the jwplayer element `$("iframe").contents().find(jwplayer_element).jwplayer().stop();`

Comment: it is added i am trying what you sent me go ahead and post it as a answer if it works i will except it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the iframe node and try to call the `jwplayer()` API which will not work. If your iframe is in the same domain, you can access the jwplayer node located *inside* the iframe and call the API.

```
$("#rokuvideo").contents().find("#se_video").jwplayer().stop();
```

Or

```
$("#rokuvideo").contentWindow.jwplayer().stop();
```

Comment: do i need to change anything?

Comment: Yeah, `jwplayer_element` should be the jwplayer node inside the iframe.

Comment: try the second solution if the first doesn't work well

Comment: ok on the top one do i need to add getElementByid in side of the find method?

Comment: no need, just use a CSS selector like `.find("#id")`

Comment: I added the code for the page the i frame is including my question is do i put

       .find("#se_video")

Comment: i added that if you go to tvstartup.com and click on roku and play the video then click the Click To Close on the top left of the video you will see i just keeps playing

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to set the src of the iframe to about:blank and then when you load it (if the user asks for it again) set it back to the needed src.
For example using a bootstrap modal

```
$('#modalVideoDIV').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
  // set src of iframe blank here (or to a silent page)
  $('#iframe').attr('src','about:blank');
})

$('#modalVideoDIV').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  // set src of iframe to video
  $('#iframe').attr('src','YOUR SRC HERE');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

or maybe better one by using this on hide:

```
$('#iframe').attr('src',$('#iframe').attr('src'));
```

which reloads the frame and then it's stopped.